# flash textfiled line .....for help

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class test extends Sprite
    {
        private var _textFiled:TextField;
        public function test()
        {
            _textFiled = new TextField();
            _textFiled.text = ".  2011年8月15日晚，据传<a href='http://www.google.com.hk'>Google</a> 将以 <font size = '12'>40 </font> 美元现金每股，总价 125 亿美元，收购摩托罗拉移动";
            _textFiled.width = 300;
            _textFiled.wordWrap = true;
            _textFiled.multiline = true;
            var st:String = "";
            for (var i:int = 0; i < _textFiled.numLines; i++) {
                var s:String = _textFiled.getLineText(i) + "\n    ";
                st += s;
            }
            _textFiled = new TextField();
            _textFiled.width = 300;
            _textFiled.wordWrap = true;
            _textFiled.multiline = true;
            _textFiled.htmlText = st;

            addChild(_textFiled);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have such a demand, I want to use textfiled reality a text, the text contains the HTML code, I think in line with a TAB after, I know textfiled in one of the getlineText method, and then back to add a "\ t"

```
var strText:string = "";
for(var i:int =9;i<textfile.numLine;i++) {

  var str:String = textfiled.getlineText(i) + "\t";
  strText += str;
}
textfile.htmlText = strText ;
```

But this can only get text, HTML code filtering, I come from China, first time in here to ask questions, thank everybody.

Comment: I was wrong,  var st:String = "";
            for (var i:int = 0; i < _textFiled.numLines; i++) {
                var s:String = _textFiled.getLineText(i) + "\t   ";
                st += s;
            }

Comment: I'm sorry, ha ha, is that I don't have a clearly stated,

I want to in a row of textfiled front plus a "\ t", but this textfiled contain HTML character, I should do?

Comment: Right, forgot to say, Chinese each word width and your English, originally I started to think different calculation each word in English and the width of the width of the characters, but I later found out that do not, ask everybody has what good method didn't?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs won't be shown in html. If multiple spaces are ok, insert as many `&nbsp;` as needed. If tabs are needed in the middle of a line, it would be necessary to calculate how many spaces are actually needed. In that case, when using flash, it would probably be easier to create multiple TextFields, one for each column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you don't want to lose the HTML formatting, you need to get the text using `_textFiled.htmlText`. Then if you want to read it line by line, it's quite tricky because both `<p>` and `<br>` are going to create new lines. Depending on your input, maybe you can just split the string by `<br>` tags:

```
var lines:Array = _textFiled.htmlText.split("<br>");
for(var i:int =9;i<lines.length;i++) {

  var str:String = lines[i] + "\t";
  strText += str;
}
```

But again, it depends on the input - if it's user generated, there's a lot more parsing you need to do. If not, and you know how the HTML is going to be formatted, it's much easier.

Comment: Thank your answer, but this might not.

Comment: var lines:Array = _textFiled.htmlText.split("<br>");
So can't get "<br>"

Comment: Because of the textfiled in htmltText don't contain < br/>